# Xcode project fails to compile

Tags: c++, xcode

ALL,

I'm trying to set up an Xcode project for my application.

I did created a project successfully with its dylib libraries and one a library. I successfully set the dependencies - 2 dylibs are depend on the a library.

After that I am able to successfully compile the a library. There is no errors.

However trying to compile one of the dylib that depends on it I'm getting the error. The Build Log as it shows inside Xcode is as follows:

```
Ld /Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Products/Debug/liblibsqlite.dylib normal x86_64
    cd /Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/libsqlite
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk -L/Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Products/Debug -L/Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/dbinterface/build/Debug -F/Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Intermediates/libsqlite.build/Debug/libsqlite.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/libsqlite.LinkFileList -install_name /usr/local/lib/liblibsqlite.dylib -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -stdlib=libc++ -ldbinterface -single_module -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Intermediates/libsqlite.build/Debug/libsqlite.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/libsqlite_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/Build/Products/Debug/liblibsqlite.dylib

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/igorkorot/dbhandler/dbhandler/dbinterface/build/Debug'
ld: library not found for -ldbinterface
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't understand this. The libdbinterface.a was built successfully. I am able to select this library in the Build Phases->Link Binary With Libraries, but for some reason the Xcode can't find it.

Now the big question is: How do I fix it?

Thank you for any information you can give.

Comment: you should install compiled library somewhere where linker/loader will find it

Comment: @strangeqargo, what do you mean? I can't install it because it is failing. And the command that fails is auto-generated by the Xcode